Two symfony projects with one login
I need a tip please. I have two Symfony WebApps that can be accessed on different subdomains. I basically want to be able to log in to WebApp_A as a user. So far no problem. But now I have links in WebApp_A to routes from WebApp_B which should only be accessible when a user is logged in. But I don't want the user to have to log in to WebApp_B again when it is called up. How can I implement this?
My research always leads me to SingleSignOn, but there are many implementation options. Which is the most suitable for the approach I described? I have a feeling that it could be an implementation with JWT.
I am grateful for every link and every tutorial that helps me further.
Thanks for your tips

Does this answer your question? Symfony 3 sharing cookies across sub-domains?

You can store ans share your sessions in a database, so the both applications connect from the same session stored in database. It's easy to configure just look for "PdoSessionHandler to store sessions in the database" in symfony site
